# c++ metaprogram, member type test?

Tags: c++, templates, metaprogramming

I try to write a template meta function to test "is a type `T` has a member type, named `type`".

here is the code:

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <type_traits>

template <typename T, typename E = void>
struct has_type;
// branch 1
template <typename T, typename E>
struct has_type : std::false_type {};
// branch 2
template <typename T>
struct has_type<
    T, std::enable_if_t<std::is_same_v<typename T::type, typename T::type>, T>
> : std::true_type {};


struct with_type {using type = void;};
struct without_type {};

int main()
{
    std::cout<< has_type< with_type >::value <<std::endl;
    std::cout<< has_type< without_type >::value <<std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

I imagined, compiler will first try to use branch 2, if the type `T` has the member type `type`, we get `std::true_type`.
Or fail to find `T::type`, then SFINAE and use branch 1, we get `std::false_type`

But the two output is both `false`.

Is there anything I understand wrong?

Answer (score 4):

The branch 1, i.e. the primary template, the default value of the 2nd template parameter is `void`; to make the branch 2, i.e. the specialization to be selected, the 2nd template argument should yield type `void` instead of `T`, when the condition is satisfied.

```
// branch 2
template <typename T>
struct has_type<
    T, std::enable_if_t<std::is_same_v<typename T::type, typename T::type>, void>
//                                                                          ^^^^
> : std::true_type {};
```

Or just

```
template <typename T>
struct has_type<
    T, std::void_t<typename T::type>
> : std::true_type {};
```

[LIVE](https://wandbox.org/permlink/XP5x27OHaLJlHO2Y)